# How to prepare application data in background?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm developing a Xamarin Forms application, but I don't think my question is Xamarin specific.
After the user enters pin code (of course only if pin was correct), I show him the tabbed page. Each of these pages has some controls, but more importantly, each of them have to fetch some data from the web, using asynchronous calls. Now, since my application has several tabs, I want to fetch all the data for each of them in parallel (non-consecutively). What I've implemented so far, is this:

```
    public MainTabbedPage(bool requirePin)
    {
        if (requirePin)
        {
            Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PinEntryPage(this));
        }
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void InitializeChildren()
    {
        try
        {
            var page1 = new Page1();
            page1.RefreshData();

            var page2 = new Page2();
            page2.RefreshButtons();
            page2.RefreshData();

            var page3 = new Page3();
            page3.RefreshData();

            Children.Add(page1);
            Children.Add(page2);
            Children.Add(page3);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // some error handling...
        }
    }
```

while all `RefreshData()` and `RefreshButtons()` look like this:

```
    public void RefreshData()
    {
        Task.Run(
            () =>
            {
                var data = ApiSingleton.Instance.GetData().Result;
                // some data manipulations
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => /* some UI manipulation*/);
                }
            });
    }
```

Now, while this seems to be doing right, I wonder if it's a correct way of doing it, and if not, what is?

Comment: `GetData()` seems to a Task. So you can simply await his result, after making `RefreshData` async. No need for a `Task.Run()` there imo

Comment: The `GetData()` looks like an async method (since you touch the `Result`) so why not actually make the whole chain properly async and not throw around tasks?

Comment: It is async indeed, thanks. btw it means that I won't need `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`, right?

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
public MainTabbedPage(bool requirePin)
{
    if (requirePin)
    {
        Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PinEntryPage(this));
    }
    InitializeComponent();
}

public async void InitializeChildren()
{
    try
    {
        var page1 = new Page1();
        await page1.RefreshData();

        var page2 = new Page2();
        await page2.RefreshButtons();
        await page2.RefreshData();

        var page3 = new Page3();
        await page3.RefreshData();

        Children.Add(page1);
        Children.Add(page2);
        Children.Add(page3);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // some error handling...
    }
}
```

And for the methods refresh methods:

```
public async Task RefreshData()
{
    var data = await ApiSingleton.Instance.GetData();
    // some data manipulations
    // you are on the UI thread here 
    // so there is no nead for BeginInvokeOnMainThread       
}
```

As an alternative to speed things up you might want to start the data referesh for all pages at once. If that is what you want, change InitializeChildren to something like this:

```
public async void InitializeChildren()
{
    try
    {
        var page1 = new Page1();
        var refreshPage1Task = page1.RefreshData();

        var page2 = new Page2();
        var refreshButtonsPage2Task = page2.RefreshButtons();
        var refreshPage2Task = page2.RefreshData();

        var page3 = new Page3();
        var refreshPage3Task = page3.RefreshData();

        await Task.WhenAll( new Task[] {
           refreshPage1Task, refreshPage2Task,
           refreshPage3Task, refreshButtonsPage2Task } );

        Children.Add(page1);
        Children.Add(page2);
        Children.Add(page3);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // some error handling...
    }
}
```

This will start the refresh on all pages at once, so the network operations can run concurrently. The return to UI thread after each invocation will still occur. `Task.WhenAll` will ensure that the pages will be appended to the Children collection only after all refresh operations are finished.

Comment: How waiting for children pages to be initialized before adding them to the page will speed things up?

Comment: Also, starting fetching data before user provides the correct pin doesn't sound good to me... Do you think it's okay? Is it secure?

Comment: I suppose the GetData method is doing some kind of data access. This means that when the data are loaded from disk or from the network, the other tasks can already begin. Suppose that the network request would take 1 second to complete - then the original code would take three seconds to finish, but the concurrent version would take jsut a little over one second, because all the requests would run at the same time.

Comment: If the data that are being loaded are sensitive, you can of course defer their loading after the pin is entered - call the InitializeChildren method after the pin is verified

Comment: hm, wasn't the data fetched concurrently in the code I provided?

Comment: Yes, in the one you provided the data were fetched concurrently, but you needed the Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread. Also, the pages are added in Children before the request is finished (which might be what you want). In the async/await variant you don't to go back to UI thread manually, but at the cost that the network requests run one by one, if you don't use the second technique I mentioned.